# Android Studio - Need help creating a button from a Style Sheet (CSS)

Tags: android, css, button

StackOverflow! Im new to Android programming so I dont have a lot of experience. I was wondering if you could help me create 3 simple buttons.

The color of the buttons should be green, blue and red. Outline of the boxes needs to be thin and glowing.

If you look at the screenshot below you can see the buttons i want.

http://prntscr.com/6rmbks

Short explained, I want to convert the CSS stylesheet of the buttons to android, if that is possible..

Here is the CSS code:

```
.message {
    margin: auto auto 20 px;
    width: 376 px;
    - webkit - font - smoothing: antialiased;
    text - transform: uppercase;
    font - size: 13 px;
    text - align: center;
    border: 1 px solid #2AF16A;
    color: # fff;
    padding: 10 px;
    - moz - border - radius: 2 px;
    - webkit - border - radius: 2 px;
    border - radius: 2 px;
    - webkit - box - shadow: 0 0 16 px green, inset 0 0 20 px green;
    - moz - box - shadow: 0 0 16 px green, inset 0 0 20 px green;
    box - shadow: 0 0 16 px green, inset 0 0 20 px green
}
.login - input {
    margin - bottom: 15 px;
    - webkit - font - smoothing: antialiased;
    background - color: rgba(0, 255, 252, .05);
    background - image: -webkit - linear - gradient(rgba(0, 192, 255, .05), rgba(0, 192, 255, 0), rgba(0, 192, 255, .05));
    background - image: -moz - linear - gradient(rgba(0, 192, 255, .05), rgba(0, 192, 255, 0), rgba(0, 192, 255, .05));
    background - image: -o - linear - gradient(rgba(0, 192, 255, .05), rgba(0, 192, 255, 0), rgba(0, 192, 255, .05));
    border: 1 px solid #2ACBF3;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3), inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3), inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3), inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 192, 255, .3);
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease, -webkit-transform 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: border 200ms ease, -moz-transform 0s ease;
    -o-transition: border 200ms ease, -o-transform 0s ease;
    outline: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: # fff;
    padding: 10 px;
    width: 376 px;
    font - family: Menlo, Consolas, Monaco, "Lucida Console", monospace
}
.error {
    margin: auto auto 20 px;
    width: 376 px;
    - webkit - font - smoothing: antialiased;
    text - transform: uppercase;
    font - size: 13 px;
    text - align: center;
    border: 1 px solid# F44747;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10 px;
    - moz - border - radius: 2 px;
    - webkit - border - radius: 2 px;
    border - radius: 2 px;
    - webkit - box - shadow: 0 0 16 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3), inset 0 0 20 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3);
    - moz - box - shadow: 0 0 16 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3), inset 0 0 20 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3);
    box - shadow: 0 0 16 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3), inset 0 0 20 px rgba(244, 71, 71, .3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more about creating custom buttons natively, you should look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html and learn from there.

For a generator, you can probably input your css into [here](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) and it should get you started!

Comment: I mean, I dont want to make a custom button from scratch. I want to convert the CSS to Android, to make a button.. If that is possible

Comment: Take a look at the *here* location, that directs to http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Comment: Yes, I have been using that tool before, but I just couldnt make it work... If you go to this site http://www.cssportal.com/online-css-editor/ and paste in the CSS code of my three classes, you can see the preview im looking for. I dont understand why it has to be so advanced to make a button.. CSS code > Android code

Answer (score 0):

Native Android apps do **not** use CSS to generate themes for components.

They use an XML based syntax that can specify properties about the button (e.g. color, size, padding, etc)

The only way to easily create the style you require is by using a 9-patch image which is an image that has its stretchable area defined. I believe  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0sIJftfjz4) explains it rather well.

Comment: Can I use PhantomJS to convert CSS into a PNG image? If that is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: No idea. I am an Android dev, not a JS dev!